# How to set bgcolor in td tag based on some condition in <c:out> tag of jstl in jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have to show red color in bgcolor of  whenever `r.beam_energy-row.beam_energy`is not equal to zero otherwise green color if difference is equal to 0.

In this way I have many column and whenever the difference is not zero,then the column should be of red color otherwise of green.

The code in jsp page is

```
<td><c:out value="${r.beam_current-row.beam_current}"  ></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.beam_energy-row.beam_energy}" ></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag1_rb-row.st2_vs2_bag1_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag2_rb-row.st2_vs2_bag2_rb}" ></c:out</td>
```

I can use javascript if needed for displaying colour in td tag based on value of **`<c:out> tag`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used style tag in td tag in following way-

`<td scope="row" style="${r.beam_energy-row.beam_energy eq 0 ? 'background-color: green':'background-color: red'}">
<c:out value="${r.beam_energy-row.beam_energy}" >
</c:out>
</td>`